# Python Reading values from Excel as DataFrame and Writing to a particular variable of a file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading all the values from an excel as python Dataframe, now i need to write the values to a particular variable of a config file

Eg:

```
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == "__main__":
   input = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/ABC/SampleExcel.xlsx')
   dfs = {sheet: seg_sheet.parse(sheet) for sheet in seg_sheet.sheet_names}
   values = dfs['Sheet1'].to_dict('records')
```

I am able to read the values, but now I need to write the values to a particular variable of a config (another python file).

Output File --------- 
output.py

```
var1 =
var2 = 
var3 =
```

So i need to read the excel files of multiple sheets and write it to a particular variable of a python output file

If the variable in output file - already has a value , I need to overwrite the values

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ConfigParser`. `StringIO` is used to simulate a file in the following example. Its some kind of workaround to add and remove the [Section] tag again. Without the [Section] tag, the generated file is a runable python script. You only need to be careful with strings, because the `ConfigParser` does not add question marks to strings.

```
import ConfigParser
import StringIO

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
cfgfilepath = 'C:/temp/output.py'

#read and add "[Section]"
with open(cfgfilepath, 'rb') as configfile:
    filecontent = configfile.read()
bufin = StringIO.StringIO("[Section]\r\n%s"%(filecontent,))

config.readfp(bufin)
bufin.close()

#set values
var1 = 1
var2 = [3,2]
var3 = "'sdaf'"

#set new value or replace existing
config.set('Section','var1',var1)
config.set('Section','var2',var2)
config.set('Section','var3',var3)

bufout = StringIO.StringIO()
config.write(bufout)
filecontent = bufout.getvalue().split("\n")
bufout.close()

#remove "[Section]" and save to file
with open(cfgfilepath, 'wb') as configfile: 
    for linenr, line in enumerate(filecontent):
        if linenr >= 1:
            configfile.write("%s\r\n"%(line,))
```

The script above produces following file (`output.py`).

```
var1 = 1
var2 = [3, 2]
var3 = 'sdaf'
```

Comment: This needs to be done in .py file and not on .cfg or .config or .ini file. I am not able to find any parser to write in .py file similar to configparser

Comment: I attached the sample code. Now you should get an executable .py file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i have a different solution given below. Can you check and say me whether the below solution is good to go and i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have parsed the excel sheet using pandas and mapped each sheet name to values in that sheet and written the output to a python file (.py). This solution works for all cases. Can I know like whether the below solution is good to go.

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":

output_file = 'E:/temp/output.py'

input_sheet = pd.ExcelFile('E:/temp/Excel1.xlsx')

input_sheet_config_list = []

for sheet in input_sheet .sheet_names:
    sheet_vals = input_sheet .parse(sheet).to_dict('records')
    input_sheet_config_list .append(sheet + " = " + str(sheet_vals))

with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    for item in input_sheet_config_list :
        f.write("%s\n" %item)
    f.close()
```